# Why is the stack count resetting?

Tags: c#

For some reason, when the loadStack() method finishes, it's count resets to 0. no idea why.
here's my method:

```
    static Stack<string> Proxies = new Stack<string>();

    private static void loadStack()
    {
        foreach (string s in File.ReadLines(pfile))
        {
            Proxies.Push(s);
            Console.WriteLine(Proxies.Count());
        }
    }
```

and here's my main method:

```
    static string pfile;  
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        pfile = Console.ReadLine();  
        loadStack();
    }
```

It goes through the entire file fine, but once it finishes the last line, the count resets to 0.

Comment: where is `loadStack` called?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, it's hard to help you at the moment. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: sorry, i may have accidentally forgot to write the loadstack() method.

Comment: That's rather hard to believe. Assuming the given `pfile` exists and contains lines (sounds like `loadStack` is executed and counts are written to the console), are you checking the right stack object (`Proxies`) after `loadStack` is finished? And if so, are you sure you don't `Pop()` out the values from that object?

Comment: As it is now, with the code you provided (and using a valid file containing lines) after `loadStack()` is executed, `Proxies` *does* contain exactly as many items, as the last output to console suggested. -- So you must be doing something else and/or different.

Answer (score -1):

Following code works perfectly AND even after loadStack method is finished, Main function prints "3" as expected. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rtLjAZ) is the C# fiddle link for your reference.

```
public class Program
{
    static Stack<string> Proxies = new Stack<string>();
    static List<string> lst = new List<string>{"a","b","c"};

    public static void Main()
    {
        loadStack();
        Console.WriteLine(Proxies.Count);
    }

    private static void loadStack()
    {
        foreach (string s in lst)
        {
            Proxies.Push(s);
            Console.WriteLine(Proxies.Count);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: `Stack<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. Using `System.Linq`, `Count()` works perfectly fine (and without compilation errors).

Comment: yeah, my bad. I was using fiddle so got confused. Thanks, i'll edit my response